# Time to reach a speed given the acceleration equation

Tags: functions, derivatives, physics, classical-mechanics

I have modeled the acceleration of a car, and here is the speed of this car with respect to the time :
$$\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{6.21}{v}-0.046-0.000137v^2$$

Now, how can I find the time needed to reach a given speed ?

Comment: It's not the "speed ... with respect to the time", that equation is the "acceleration with respect to velocity".  As to how to solve it, for speed wrt to time, what do you know about solving nonlinear differential equations?

Comment: What is your initial condition?

Comment: OP: @Paul may be observing that you are positing (momentarily) infinite acceleration when $v = 0$.  Not necessarily a problem, but you might want to confirm this is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You could separate variables:
$$\int_{t_1}^{t_2} dt=\int_{v_1}^{v_2} \frac{dv}{\frac{a}{v}-b-cv^2}$$

(Where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are the constants in your expression for the acceleration.)

Not sure if it is possible to find an antiderivative for the right hand side, though. As Bye_World commented, you might need to use numerical methods. [Euler's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) for solving ODE's is a simple one. [Runge-Kutta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods) is slightly more complicated, but more accurate.

Edit: Nicolas pointed out in the comments that we actually can find an antiderivative for the right hand side. WolframAlpha gives (assuming $v$ is not zero):
$$t_2-t_1 = \sum_{\{\omega\,:\,a-b\omega-c\omega^2=0\}}\frac{\omega \ln(\frac{v_2-\omega}{v_1-\omega})}{3c\omega^2+b}$$
The sum is over the three roots of $a-b\omega-c\omega^3$. The expression is still pretty complicated but it gives you the time interval to accelerate from $v_1$ to $v_2$, as desired.

Comment: OK, I will try this

Comment: Actually Wolframalpha is able to integrate the function: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%2F%286.21-0.046x-0.000137x%5E3%29